# Python flask app container image cannot resolve internal modules

Tags: python, docker, flask, module, containers

I have created a simple python flask API project using pycharm. It works great when I run using IDE and API's can be tested without any problem on localhost. BUT when I create a docker image of it and run the container on localhost, it always throw following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app.py", line 2, in <module>
    from application import db, application
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'application'
```

It has following directory structure

```
MyFlaskAPI
|
  -Application
  |
   - __init__.py
| 
  -Models
  |  
    -Model.py
|
   -- Other project folders e.g. template, include, libs etc
|
  - app.py
  - config.py
  - requirements.txt
  - Dockerfile
  - Few other config files
```

**init**.py looks is as follows:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

app.py is as follows:

```
from flask import request
from application import db, app
from model.models import FirstModel, SecondItemModel, ThirdModel
```

Docker file as follows:

```
FROM python:3

ADD app.py /
ADD requirements.txt /

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "python", "./app.py", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3 
ADD app.py / 
ADD requirements.txt / 
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt 
#EXPOSE 5000 
CMD [ "python", "./app.py", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Any suggestions/help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile as well.

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal Please find the Dockerfile as follows:

`FROM python:3

ADD app.py /
ADD requirements.txt /

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

#EXPOSE 5000

CMD [ "python", "./app.py", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]`

Comment: It seems that you only add app.py not the rest of your app.You should add something like: ADD MyFlaskAPI/

Comment: Ahh. My bad. Being a novice, I made such stupid mistake. My bad and many thanks for mentioning it. I just added rest of required modules and it works.

Comment: @Amit Kindly reward Victor with an upvote as his advice helped you in solving your issue. Thanks.

Comment: @KapilKhandelwal I would have loved to upvoted Victor comment but unfortunately I dont have enough reputation points due to very less activity here in recent past.
Victor kindly accept my hearty thanks as upvote for now :). Best Regards.